# facebook always returns FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I have set public_profile permission in place of basic_info as per the new documents of facebook. But it returns me FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed state when i try try to authenticate. And works fine with basic_info permission. I m quite confuse which permission has to set. If i set basic_info is it going to create any issue in future? My facebook sdk version is 3.8.0